# Why does inserting a printf statement make my function work correctly?

Tags: c, printf, openmp

Here's the basic premise of my code:

```
while(norm_of_error > tol){
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i = 1; i <= N*N; i++){
    //printf("thread id: %d\n",omp_get_thread_num());
      :
    int val = based on i
      :
    #pragma omp critical
    x[i-1] = val;
  }
  #pragma omp barrier
  iter++;
}
```

In short, I am solving Ax = b using the Jacobi iterative method. My problem is that, with the `printf()` statement uncommented, the `norm_of_error` tends to zero and the while loop ends. However, by simply commenting out the `printf()` statement, this doesn't happen. Can anyone give me a hint as to why the `printf()` statement has any impact? I'm guessing that the issue has to do with the call to omp_get_thread_num(), but I don't see why that would make any difference.

Edit: I changed the `printf()` statement to `printf("hi\n");` and the code works. Comment that out, and the code doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show more of your code,perhaps the code of the whole function?

Comment: Either this is C, or this is C++. Which is it??

Comment: You need to show more code. I implemented Jacobi iterative method recently with OpenMP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code that works with a `printf()` statement present, but fails when it is removed, is usually a sign of some invalid operation affecting memory in the program somewhere (e.g. falling off the end of an array, dereferencing `NULL`, etc).    The misbehaving code may be in some other section of the program entirely (e.g. not within the function that contains the `printf()` statement)

That is even more likely when the offending `printf()` statement is something obviously innocent, and without any side effects that can affect behaviour of other code (such as `printf("Hi\n")`).

The reason is that the presence of the extra `printf()` does actually affect layout of memory for the program as a whole.   So the offending code (which may be in some completely unrelated part of the program) still overwrites memory, but the consequence changes  (e.g. overwriting some data the program is permitted to change, rather than some area of memory that causes the operating system to terminate the program).

This is true whether or not the code is multithreaded.

Without complete code that illustrates the problem (i.e. a small sample that someone else can compile, build, and run to get the same symptom) it is not possible to be more specific.

Comment: Regarding the *etc.*: It could also be that a variable was not initialized, and the call to printf overwrites the value it is initialized to (on the stack). Wasted hours searching for an invalid array index...

Comment: @mafu - the scenario you describe is pretty unlikely, since arguments to `printf()` - after the format string - are passed by value and not modified.  As I said, the invalid operation on memory is likely to be in some code other than the call of `printf()` - particularly in situations, as in this question, involving innocent use such as `printf("Hi\n")`.

Comment: Yes! The uninitialized variable was elsewhere in this case, and printf affected it :)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't posted your code so we can't know for sure, but this typically arises because you are trying to share data amongst threads without adequately indicating that the data is to be shared.

With the `printf` removed, your program is loading the data into a register, and when it needs the data again, it remembers the value in the register rather than fetching it from memory again, thus it doesn't see any changes your other threads may have made.

With the `printf` in place, your program doesn't hold the data in register -- maybe it can't afford to spend a register that way, or it can't determine that a function call is incapable of changing the data (sure, it's just `printf`, but it might not be special cased, and even if it is, the compiler is better at finding loopholes that might allow `printf` to change data than you are) -- so it rereads the data from memory after the call to `printf`, and thus sees whatever prior changes that have been made in other threads.

Another thing the `printf` could change is timing: I/O statements are pretty slow as compared to computation, and there is likely *some* amount of synchronization happening inside the I/O library; your `print` might be acting as a pseudo-barrier that is preventing a race condition from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

*Keep in mind that C and C++ are different languages*.

The [C FAQ](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/C-faq.top.html) has as section on [strange problems](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/funnybugs.html):

> comp.lang.c FAQ list · Question 16.5
>
> *Q: This program runs perfectly on one machine, but I get weird results on another. Stranger still, adding or removing a debugging printout changes the symptoms...*
>
> A: Lots of things could be going wrong; here are a few of the more common things to check:
>
> - uninitialized local variables [footnote] (see also question 7.1)
> - integer overflow, especially on 16-bit machines, especially of an intermediate result when doing things like a * b / c (see also question 3.14)
> - undefined evaluation order (see questions 3.1 through 3.4)
> - omitted declaration of external functions, especially those which return something other than int, or have ``narrow'' or variable arguments (see questions 1.25, 11.3, 14.2, and 15.1)
> - dereferenced null pointers (see section 5)
> - improper malloc/free use: assuming malloc'ed memory contains 0, assuming freed storage persists, freeing something twice, corrupting the malloc arena (see also questions 7.19 and 7.20)
> - pointer problems in general (see also questions 16.7 and 16.8)
> - mismatch between printf format and arguments, especially trying to print long ints using %d (see questions 12.7 and 12.9)
> - trying to allocate more memory than an unsigned int can count, especially on machines with limited memory (see also questions 7.16 and 19.23)
> - array bounds problems, especially of small, temporary buffers, perhaps used for constructing strings with sprintf [footnote] (see also questions 7.1, 12.21, and 19.28)
> - invalid assumptions about the mapping of typedefs, especially size_t (see question 7.15)
> - floating point problems (see questions 14.1 and 14.4a)
> - anything you thought was a clever exploitation of the way you believe code is generated for your specific system
>
> Proper use of function prototypes can catch several of these problems; lint would catch several more. See also questions 16.3, 16.4, and 18.4.